# Javascript: Setting all array values to the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a new array (of X elements) with all the elements set to 0.
X is set before.
Anyone could make the most compact and easy code for that? Thank you for your 
help.

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the negativity :D

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function:

```
function makeArray(size, defaultValue) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) arr.push(defaultValue);
    return arr;
}

var myArr = makeArray(10, 0);
```